# What is the best way for a server process to wait for client input/messages

Tags: c++, c, client-server, producer-consumer

Apologies if this question seems a tad open ended or too vague, I'm not the best C/Cpp programmer (either language is acceptable to solve this problem).

Suppose there are two running processes, a client and a server (they could be viewed as producer and consumer as well, but I think client and server might be better here).  The server is a "child" (sort of, see below) process of the client such that it has been created to act somewhat as an offload.  Over time the client generates several jobs which it then offloads to the server it created.  Depending on the job, the server may or may not send back to the client information regarding job completion.  As an aside, some might suggest that this could be done with threads.  For reasons I won't get into, threads will not work here.  The client and server should not be sharing memory (there may or may not be shared memory, its possible the client and server are two different machines: the code I'm writing should support both possibilities).

The server has a very long initialization period and thus must always be running, hence the idea of the second process being a server.  It therefore must always be listening for any messages from the client.  A simple pseudo-code/C example is given below

```
int main() {
    ...
    client_pid = getpid();
    pid = fork();
    if(pid > 0) {
        /* sets up connection with client, based on what connection type has been
         * given (shared memory, sockets, etc).  I don't know anything   
         * about what type of connection is established only that all
         * communication is handled by the wait_For_Jobs and generate_Jobs functions
        */
        start_Server(client_pid, connection_type);
        wait_For_Jobs();
    } else {
        // gets information needed to send messages to server
        contact_info = wait_for_connection(); 
        generate_Jobs(contact_info);
    }
}
```

This is a very, very rough outline of what I want.  The question that I have is related to the "wait_For_Jobs" function.  Unfortunately, the connection_type will not be known until runtime and thus this question might have several different answers depending on what type of communication method is used (ie shared memory, sockets, etc).  For simplicity then, assume that shared memory is the communication type being used (say boost interprocess).  With this in mind, what is the best and most efficient way for the server to wait for input from the client?  One possible approach is to use a while loop somewhat in the fashion given below.

```
void wait_For_Jobs() {
    while(true) {
        if(check_If_Message_Received_Over_Shared_Memory){
            // handle message
        }
    }
}
```

However, I suspect that this will be very inefficient; the process is always "spinning its wheels".  Somewhat of a fix would be to put the process to "sleep" at the end of the while loop for a period of time.  This isn't really too different from just running the code in the while loop (in fact its the same thing); it just lowers resource usage at the expense of response time.  Ideally, the process should just be in somewhat of a standby mode and start computing once it receives a message.  However, I'm not sure how you would do such a thing in C or Cpp.  With that in mind, is there a better alternative?

Comment: *" its possible the client and server are two different machines"* - that rather rules out shared memory, I would be thinking in terms of sockets.

Comment: Theres an if statement that determines at runtime how things are run. This allows users to determine to locally run (given the hardware users have available) or not. The crux of this question is whether it is possible to lower research usage (ie cpu utilization) by not using a while loop as mentioned above in the question. Even if a semaphore is used, for example, I suspect a while loop will exist somewhere in the compiled code. The question is whether this loop is more efficient. In a system like android, the OS can put a process to sleep and wake it when a message is sent to it

Comment: If something similar can be done in C/CPP (instead of doing this by default a program can request an OS to do something similar) then I think it would be much more efficient then a semaphore.  In fact, semaphores are, to my understanding, primarily used for resource  management and allocation; not reducing utilization.

Comment: With sockets the server process will sleep (block) until it receives a message.

Comment: Isn't that dependent on the OS?

Comment: I don't know any OSs that wouldn't.

Comment: If you want to be able to run the server on a different machine from the client, you must go for sockets. Implementing a dual communication mechanism that uses sometimes shared memory, sometimes another way, will give you headaches. Sockets work transparently in local (same machine) or remote (different machine). You should define clearly what amount of data will be shared between client and server (you didn't give detail about that in your question). Sockets offers a way for the server to wait for a request in sleep mode, and to be waken up when the request is received.

Answer (score 0):

If you use shared memory you will need to block on a semaphore which is raised when another request appears.

If you use sockets, use a blocking receive.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't you need to continuously check the semaphore?  That is, conceptually wouldn't this be the same as running a while loop (in terms of resource usage)?  And the same for the blocking receive.  Specifically, if I were to block on a semaphore, a while loop in the actual code I write won't be needed (at least I don't think, I"m not familiar with semaphores in C/Cpp).  However, in order to check if the process is still blocked, I suspect there has to be a while loop somewhere once the code is compiled.

Comment: I guess another way of asking this question is, do you get a performance increase by using either a semaphore or blocking receive?

Comment: No. Semaphore and blocking reads block *in the kernel* and are awoken by events. No spin loop. Re your last question, 'performance increase' compared to what?

Comment: in terms of cpu utilization.  You somewhat answered this by stating that there wouldn't be any spin loops though.